# Bluetooth External device Pairing

Tags: android

I am working on bluetooth application which will interact with the external bluetooth device ,when i was trying to connect the device it will ask for pairing after done with the passcode process its disconnects the device

here is my log

```
04-02 18:02:32.326: E/bt-att(1202): device already in iniator white list
04-02 18:02:32.326: D/DeviceControlActivity(22022): Connect request result=true
04-02 18:02:32.336: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18397): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
04-02 18:02:32.466: I/BluetoothBondStateMachine(1202): bondStateChangeCallback: Status: 1 Address: 90:59:AF:0B:7C:74 newState: 0
04-02 18:02:32.466: D/BluetoothAdapterProperties(1202): Failed to remove device: 90:59:AF:0B:7C:74
04-02 18:02:32.466: I/BluetoothBondStateMachine(1202): Bond State Change Intent:90:59:AF:0B:7C:74 OldState: 11 NewState: 10
04-02 18:02:32.466: W/BluetoothEventManager(18397): CachedBluetoothDevice for device 90:59:AF:0B:7C:74 not found, calling readPairedDevices().
04-02 18:02:32.466: D/BluetoothAdapterService(1105887648)(1202): Get Bonded Devices being called
04-02 18:02:32.476: D/BluetoothAdapterProperties(1202): getBondedDevices: length=1
04-02 18:02:32.476: I/BluetoothBondStateMachine(1202): StableState(): Entering Off State
04-02 18:02:32.476: D/BluetoothAdapterService(1105887648)(1202): Get Bonded Devices being called
04-02 18:02:32.476: D/BluetoothAdapterProperties(1202): getBondedDevices: length=1
04-02 18:02:32.476: E/BluetoothEventManager(18397): Got bonding state changed for 90:59:AF:0B:7C:74, but we have no record of that device.
04-02 18:02:32.516: E/bt-btm(1202): btm_sec_disconnected - Clearing Pending flag
04-02 18:02:32.516: W/bt-btif(1202): bta_dm_act no entry for connected service cbs
04-02 18:02:32.516: E/bt-btm(1202): WL full or empty, unable to update to WL. num_entry available: 128
04-02 18:02:32.516: D/BtGatt.btif(1202): btif_gattc_upstreams_evt: Event 5
04-02 18:02:32.516: D/BtGatt.GattService(1202): onDisconnected() - clientIf=5, connId=5, address=90:59:AF:0B:7C:74
04-02 18:02:32.516: D/BluetoothGatt(22022): onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=5 device=90:59:AF:0B:7C:74
04-02 18:02:32.516: I/BluetoothLeService(22022): Disconnected from GATT server.
04-02 18:02:32.536: I/BluetoothConnectionReceiver(21952): onReceive(context, Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED flg=0x4000010 cmp=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.search.core.service.BluetoothConnectionReceiver (has extras) }, [BluetoothDevice: address=90:59:AF:0B:7C:74, alias=null, name=SenseGiz-FINDIT, majorDeviceClass=7936, deviceClass=7936])
04-02 18:02:32.536: I/BluetoothClassifier(21952): Bluetooth Device Name: SenseGiz-FINDIT
04-02 18:02:35.459: D/btif_config_util(1202): btif_config_save_file(L153): in file name:/data/misc/bluedroid/bt_config.new
04-02 18:02:58.163: W/GLSUser(914): GoogleAccountDataService.getToken()
04-02 18:02:58.954: W/GLSUser(914): [apk][apk] Permission for com.android.chrome to access oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromesync will be managed locally.
04-02 18:02:59.415: D/dalvikvm(16461): GC_CONCURRENT freed 460K, 6% free 9438K/9972K, paused 6ms+1ms, total 39ms
04-02 18:03:35.143: D/dalvikvm(686): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1311K, 19% free 13694K/16760K, paused 11ms+4ms, total 65ms
04-02 18:03:55.124: I/bt-hci(1202): BLE HCI(id=62) event = 0x01)
04-02 18:03:55.124: W/bt-btif(1202): info:x0
04-02 18:03:55.124: D/(1202): remote version info [90:59:af:0b:7c:74]: 0, 0, 0
04-02 18:03:55.144: I/BluetoothConnectionReceiver(21952): onReceive(context, Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED flg=0x4000010 cmp=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.search.core.service.BluetoothConnectionReceiver (has extras) }, [BluetoothDevice: address=90:59:AF:0B:7C:74, alias=null, name=SenseGiz-FINDIT, majorDeviceClass=7936, deviceClass=7936])
04-02 18:03:55.174: I/BluetoothBondStateMachine(1202): bondStateChangeCallback: Status: 0 Address: 90:59:AF:0B:7C:74 newState: 1
04-02 18:03:55.174: I/BluetoothBondStateMachine(1202): Bond State Change Intent:90:59:AF:0B:7C:74 OldState: 10 NewState: 11
04-02 18:03:55.174: I/BluetoothBondStateMachine(1202): Entering PendingCommandState State
04-02 18:03:55.184: D/BluetoothAdapterService(1105887648)(1202): Get Bonded Devices being called
04-02 18:03:55.184: D/BluetoothAdapterProperties(1202): getBondedDevices: length=1
04-02 18:03:55.184: W/BluetoothEventManager(18397): CachedBluetoothDevice for device 90:59:AF:0B:7C:74 not found, calling readPairedDevices().
04-02 18:03:55.184: D/BluetoothAdapterService(1105887648)(1202): Get Bonded Devices being called
04-02 18:03:55.184: D/BluetoothAdapterProperties(1202): getBondedDevices: length=1
04-02 18:03:55.184: E/BluetoothEventManager(18397): Got bonding state changed for 90:59:AF:0B:7C:74, but we have no record of that device.
04-02 18:03:55.184: I/BluetoothClassifier(21952): Bluetooth Device Name: SenseGiz-FINDIT
04-02 18:03:55.184: V/LocalBluetoothPreferences(18397): Found no reason to show the dialog - do not show dialog.
```